# Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate

Tags: semantic-ui

when I try to implement Semantic-UI Menu example, I receive error in console: `Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. slide down in <div class="menu" tabindex="-1">`

I've just opened in browser `http://example.com/vendor/semantic/ui/examples/components/menu.html`

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

turns out they are very much dependent on each other.. (but you don't have to load all of semantic ui)

so, dropdown component requires both dropdown.js and dropdown.css.. but, dropdown component requires transition.js

aaand for transition.js to work, you also need transition.css to be loaded..

so, basically:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/components/transition.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/components/dropdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/components/transition.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/components/dropdown.css">
```

more info on: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3960

cdn list: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui/2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the same issue, add the whole semantic UI CSS file to your project, not just the menu module. I got the same error when I tried to just import the dropdown and transition JS & CSS files. You might be able to get around importing the whole file if you identify which other one resolves this issue but this solved it for me.

Here's a cdn link to the css: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.css